# Android: How to remove additional padding/margin in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Can somebody tell me, why this is have an additional padding/margin top?

[image]

Comment: Probably because you have fixed it's height to 9 and the height of it's container to 15?

Comment: But it's should be in the center. How to make the `LienarLayoutCompat` center?

Comment: Not sure, please post a complete xml file that replicates it (as text, not an image) in the question.